# Change TFVC workspace url after migration to Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops, workspace, tfvc

After we migrate our on premise Azure DevOps Server 2020 to the Azure DevOps Services (in the cloud) is there a way to change the server URL of the existing tfvc workspaces to point to the new url in the cloud?  Or is the only option to create new workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

If the migration was done with the project collection import, it's enough to add the server connection to the Azure DevOps instance in visual studio.

Visual studio should recognize the server identity and the project collection identity are the same as your old server and will automatically reconnect your existing workspaces.

Afterwards you can delete the old server connection.

---

In case the migration was done with a history replay, tip migration or when the migration to the cloud changed the server identifier (a non-production upgrade was performed as part of the migration), you'll need to manually remap the workspace.

Comment: Thanks.  Will need to test it out after the dry-run migration.  In terms of the server identifier, would that only change if the org name is changed?

Comment: When you run the upgrade wizard of Azure DevOps it asks whether you want a pre-prod upgrade or a prod upgrade. If you pick pre, it will change the identifiers. There's also a commandline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2020#changeserverid